# Wrong SQL Index being used

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, indexing

I have a table with around 10M Rows on which i have 4 indexes :

```
CREATE TABLE ALLTRX2 (
ORDER_CODE nvarchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CREATEDTS datetime NULL, 
trx_date nvarchar(11) NULL, 
trx_month nvarchar(8) NULL,
payment_provider nvarchar(255) NULL, 
payment_method nvarchar(100) NULL, 
general_payment_method nvarchar(100) NULL,
amount_initial NUMERIC(30,2) NULL, 
eur_amount NUMERIC(30,2) NULL,
currency nvarchar(20) NULL,
backend_status nvarchar(255) NULL,
general_status nvarchar(50) NULL,
EMAIL nvarchar(255) NULL,
CUSTOMER_ID nvarchar(50) NULL, 
P_UID nvarchar(255) NULL, 
P_NAME nvarchar(255) NULL, 
P_USER nvarchar(255) NULL, 
COUNTRYCODE nvarchar(50) NULL, 
COUNTRY nvarchar(50) NULL,
CUSTOMER_GROUP nvarchar(50) NULL,
DELIVERYADDRESS nvarchar(255) NULL,
BILLINGADDRESS nvarchar(255) NULL, 
CREATEDTS1 DATE NULL )
```

I have the following indexes:

1. DATE :  which is a non clustered non unique index on filed CREATEDTS1
2. Clustered Index on the PK i.e. ORDER_CODE
3. EMAIL : on the EMAIL

Everything works well but when i run a simple query like :

```
SELECT * FROM ALLTRX2 
WHERE CREATEDTS1>'2018-08-02'
```

It does a table scan instead of a Index seek

But when i do

```
SELECT * FROM ALLTRX2 
WHERE CREATEDTS1='2018-08-02'
```

It does a index seek.

That makes absolutely no sense to me!

I could use WITH(INDEX(date)) but i want to find a solution otherwise.

INDEX definitions are as follows :

```
CREATE INDEX email
on ALLTRX2 (EMAIL)

CREATE INDEX date
on ALLTRX2 (CREATEDTS1)
```

I am pretty new to DB management and although I use SSMS to run queries pretty often Im not an expert regarding Indexing and DB maintenance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: include the Index definitions in your question

Comment: @Mazhar:  Is that ok now?

Comment: Does it make sense? If most of the 10 million rows are from after the date, then - this may be better than going thorugh the index. Also, what is the db? Including patch level. And then - why here, not on dba?

Comment: No, I was after the `CREATE INDEX...` for all the indexes. I want to see what other columns, if any, are included in the index definitions

Comment: @TomTom : Most of the 10 Million rows are actually before the date. Only 200k rows exists after this date

Comment: @Mazhar :CREATE INDEX date on ALLTRX2 (CREATEDTS1)

Comment: @Mazhar : CREATE INDEX email
on ALLTRX2 (EMAIL)
These 2 are the ones i created. The other one on the PK was created automatically while creating the table

Comment: What kind of queries you usually make? You could make CREATEDTS1 clustered, this could alter SQL optimizer decisions. Then you could instead of `select *` use specific fields list (and if there are few fields, include these into CREATEDTS1 index) - this also alters optimizer behavior. Then you could use `where` clause like `between date1 and date2` - this may again change results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually looking for a range of dates not a specific date. 
And this range is not a very limited range of dates maybe.

SQL Engine decides actually to scan the date index, this is not bad. 
It decides this index selection by considering statistics collected about table data.

I know such problems occur (using wrong index selection and performance issues) when execute a compiled query (whose execution plan is already decided) with very different parameter sets.

For example, if you execute a stored procedure with a single date, it can choose index seek and create and cache execution plan using index seek.
But on a later call of the stored procedure with a wide date period, index seek will fail to perform query.

But you are running a simple SELECT which will not cause an issue.

Comment: The problem is when it does a table scan it takes around 36 minutes for the query to run as opposed to 5 seconds if use WITH(INDEX(date)). I need it to use the correct index without me coercing it to. Anyway i can do that?

Comment: "Full Table Scan" is a problem. But if it is index scan vs index seek, then it is better to leave SQL Engine take the decision. But if there is a table scan, then either you have a missing index, or your filter criteria is not selective enough to choose an index. As I said, if your query has a cached execution plan, then the cached execution plan could not be suitable for every WHERE clause filtering. Maybe you can execute your query with sp_executesql that will create a new plan for every execution

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to take a look to the statistics, they may be very old and SQL Server thinks it's more efficient to do the scan rather than use the index.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-updatestats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017